# bash: Extract a specific string from file and remove characters

Tags: json, bash, parsing

I'm trying to extract a specific string value from a text file and then remove the backslash from him. the name of the value is "display_url"

My script:

```
url=$(cat /var/scripts/string.txt | grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+')

for link in $url; do
     echo 'https://'$link
done
```

output:

```
https://pastebin.com\/WRv5ir4Y
https://reddit.com\/r\/IBO\/comments\u2026
```

The desired output:

```
https://pastebin.com/WRv5ir4Y
https://reddit.com/r/IBO/comments/u2026
```

text file:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Dec 13 08:43:38 +0000 2018","id":1073136349845303297,"id_str":"1073136349845303297","text":"https:\/\/t.co\/aPu5ln7yjO\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/pBvevjSCc9\n\n#osectraining","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":961508561217052675,"id_str":"961508561217052675","name":"Online Security","screen_name":"osectraining","location":"Israel","url":"https:\/\/www.onlinesecurity.co.il","description":"OnlineSecurity provides online cyber-security training courses and certification, from beginner to advanced with the most advanced virtual labs in the field.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":2,"friends_count":51,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":1,"created_at":"Thu Feb 08 07:54:39 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1B95E0","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/961510231346958336\/d_KhBeTD_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/961510231346958336\/d_KhBeTD_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/961508561217052675\/1518076913","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"osectraining","indices":[49,62]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/aPu5ln7yjO","expanded_url":"https:\/\/pastebin.com\/WRv5ir4Y","display_url":"pastebin.com\/WRv5ir4Y","indices":[0,23]},{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/pBvevjSCc9","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.reddit.com\/r\/IBO\/comments\/9ragj7\/ioc_in_10_hours\/","display_url":"reddit.com\/r\/IBO\/comments\u2026","indices":[24,47]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"und","timestamp_ms":"1544690618369"}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe show us the input, and what you wanted as the *desired* output?

Comment: the question is edited

Comment: could there be more than 2?

Comment: Since it seems that you're [not notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225431) on post edit I just want to say that I just dit so. :)

Comment: I think you should rename your question to something like "How to remove backslashes from a string value stored in a json file using command line?", It will be more retrievable from a Web search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script into:

```
url=$(grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+' /var/scripts/string.txt )
sed 's/\\//g;s@^@https://@' <<< "$url"
```

should help.

- removed useless cat
- make use of sed to do the substitution

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: @bugnet17 I added a `g` flag to the `s` command. it should work now

Comment: In one line with `sed 's/\\//g;s@^@https://@' <<< $( grep -oP '(?<=display_url":")[^"]+' i )`, but I'm kinda miffed that we have to use both `sed` and `grep`. I know, `sed` doesn't do Perl regexes... :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use the JSON command line parser **`jq`**:

```
jq -r '"https://" + .entities.urls[].display_url' /var/scripts/string.txt
```

- `-r` stands for "return raw inputs" (strings without quotes)
- `"https://" +` concat ...
- `.entities.urls[]` ... for each item of the array `.entities.urls` ...
- `.display_url`     ...  the value of `display_url` member"

Result:

```
https://pastebin.com/WRv5ir4Y
https://reddit.com/r/IBO/comments
```

Comment: @PaulHodges thanks for your remark. Actually it's possible to embed the prefix concatenation inside the `jq` command. :)

Comment: Even better. :)

Comment: @Amessihel What is the "..."  in the ending of   https://reddit.com/r/IBO/comments…     ?

Comment: @bugnet17 Maybe a bad output from a bad copy/past of your json file. I just retested and fixed my answer just now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are needing both that `grep` and a separate `sed` to parse it is because the `grep` is able to use Perl regexes *(power...)* but `sed` can't. You probably have Perl available - use it if you do.

```
perl -pe '
   s/\\//g;
   s{.*?display_url":"}{https://};
   s{",".*display_url":"}{\nhttps://} while /display_url/;
   s/",".*/\n/;
 ' /var/scripts/string.txt
https://pastebin.com/WRv5ir4Y
https://reddit.com/r/IBO/commentsu2026
```

And there's virtually always `awk`.

```
awk '{
   gsub("\\\\","",$0);
   split($0, chnk, "display_url.:.");
   for (x=2; x<=length(chnk); x++) {
      gsub("\".*","", chnk[x]);
      printf "https://%s\n", chnk[x];
   }
}' /var/scripts/string.txt
https://pastebin.com/WRv5ir4Y
https://reddit.com/r/IBO/commentsu2026
```

But if you can't use either of those, then one `sed` to strip the backslashes and some basic shell string processing in a loop, because it's fun. :D

```
$: txt=$(sed 's/\\//g' i)
$: while [[ "$txt" =~ display_url ]]
   do txt=${txt#*display_url?:?}
      echo https://${txt%%?,*}
   done
https://pastebin.com/WRv5ir4Y
https://reddit.com/r/IBO/commentsu2026
```

Trickiest part is getting around the double-quotes in the shell parsing, but I'm sure someone can suggest a better way.

Comment: None of these care how many URL's there are, as long as there's at least one. If there could be a return without one it's easy to add skips in the `perl` and `awk` versions, though the `bash` has it built-in. ;)